# Unexplained Infinite Loop in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a subroutine that is meant to remove unwanted rows from a worksheet via Loop.

I am using Cells.Find to locate the string "Total", and then passing the Cells.Find().Row value for my Rows().EntireRow.Delete statement. I only want the subroutine to delete the row if the String is in column 2, so I am also using Cells.Find().Column and then an IF statement to delete the line if Cells.Find().Column = 2

What's really weird: If the initial segment of the If statement is TRUE, then the loop executes without issue in expected number of iterations. If the initial segment is FALSE, it loops infinitely. Here is the original code:

```
Sub Clean_Placeholder()
Dim row_bound, column_bound As Long
Dim rngFound As Range

holder_ws.Activate
WorkbookArea (*This item sets the last_row and Last_column variables*)
row_bound = last_row
column_bound = last_column
Set rngFound = Cells.Find(What:="Total", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
Do While Not rngFound Is Nothing
    row_bound = Cells.Find(What:="Total", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
    column_bound = Cells.Find(What:="Total", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
    If column_bound = 2 Then
        Rows(row_bound).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlToUp
    End If
    Set rngFound = Cells.Find(What:="Total", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
Loop

End Sub
```

As is, the code loops forever because the (If column_bound = 2) statement is FALSE. However, if I change the IF statement to something that is TRUE, the code works perfectly. E.G., If the word "Total" is present in column 16, (If column_bound = 16) would work as expected.

I'm really confused as this doesn't seem to make logical sense, but I am sure that I am not thinking of something.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: If you don't delete the Total row, then the loop will find it repeatedly. I think normally one would use `Find` and `FindNext` here.

Comment: What is the point of `WorkbookArea` and setting `row_bound` and `column_bound`?

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, putting that way makes it click in my head. I can take a look at your recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Delete Matching Rows using `Find` and `FindNext`

- It might be worth looking into `Range.AutoFilter` which could be used to do the same more efficiently and with less code.

```vb
Sub DeleteEntireRows()

    Const SEARCH_PATTERN As String = "*ToTal*" ' contains
    Const IS_TESTER As Boolean = True
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    With ws.Range("B2")
        Set rg = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With

    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = rg.Find( _
        SEARCH_PATTERN, rg.Cells(rg.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No match found using the pattern """ & SEARCH_PATTERN _
            & """ in the range """ & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ of worksheet """ _
            & ws.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim FirstRow As Long: FirstRow = cell.Row
    
    Dim urg As Range
    
    Do
        If urg Is Nothing Then
            Set urg = cell
        Else
            Set urg = Union(urg, cell)
        End If
        Set cell = rg.FindNext(cell)
    Loop While cell.Row <> FirstRow
        
    With urg.EntireRow
        If IS_TESTER Then
            MsgBox "You were about to delete the following rows:" _
                & vbLf & vbLf & .Address(0, 0) & "." & vbLf & vbLf _
                & "Set ""IS_TESTER"" to 'False' to do it for real.", _
                vbInformation
        Else
            .Delete xlShiftUp
            MsgBox "Total rows deleted.", vbInformation
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```